# Calculate Positive Streak for Pandas Rows in reverse

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

*I want to **calculate a positive streak for numbers** in a **row** in **reverse** fashion.*
I tried using **cumsum()** but that's not helping me.

The DataFrame looks as follows with the **expected output**:

```
  country  score_1 score_2 score_3 score_4 score_5  expected_streak
     U.S.     12.4    13.6    19.9      22    28.7                4
   Africa     11.1    15.5     9.2       7    34.2                1
    India     13.9     6.6    16.3    21.8    30.9                3
Australia     25.4    36.9    18.9      29     NaN                0
 Malaysia     12.8     NaN    -6.2    28.6    31.7                2
Argentina     40.7     NaN    16.3    20.1      39                2
   Canada     56.4     NaN     NaN      -2      -1                1
```

So, basically *score_5* should be *greater* than *score_4* and so on... to get a count of streak. If a number is greater than score_5 the streak count ends.

Comment: @Chris I have corrected the DataFrame values. Thank you for pointing it out.
Besides, Africa is 1 because, 34.2 > 7 but 7 is not > 9.2 so the count is 1.

Comment: @Chris That's correct, I took +1 in every value. I miscalculated with number of columns. I have changed the output. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `diff` with `cummin`:

```
df2 = df.filter(like="score_").loc[:, ::-1]
df["expected"] = df2.diff(-1, axis=1).gt(0).cummin(1).sum(1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     country  score_1  score_2  score_3  score_4  score_5  expected
0       U.S.     12.4     13.6     19.9     22.0     28.7         4
1     Africa     11.1     15.5      9.2      7.0     34.2         1
2      India     13.9      6.6     16.3     21.8     30.9         3
3  Australia     25.4     36.9     18.9     29.0      NaN         0
4   Malaysia     12.8      NaN     -6.2     28.6     31.7         2
5  Argentina     40.7      NaN     16.3     20.1     39.0         2
6     Canada     56.4      NaN      NaN     -2.0     -1.0         1
```

Comment: Yup that worked. Thank you so much. If in case I want to use in straight order and not the reverse order. What should be the change? Just the negative slicing?

Comment: @YashGhorpade In that case, take off the `loc` then use `lt` in second line `df2.diff(-1, axis=1).lt(0).cummin(1).sum(1)`